# Volume mounts differing between machines

Tags: docker

I have a docker image that I mount a folder into the container via the -v option, but on one machine the user:group inside the docker container is the owner of that folder, while on another machine the host user:group maintains ownership of the folder even inside the container, but only as the UID:GID.

I double checked the version of docker on both machines.

Is there a configuration or extra flag I'm missing to allow the container to have full UID:GID permissions to mounted volumes?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was because the UID:GID of the host and the container matched, so the container interpreted this coincidence as it owning the folders. The solution across machines was to mount /etc/passwd and /etc/group, then use -u ${GID}:$(id -g) to match users between the host and container.